# Multiple endpoints from different services in the same WCF service host

Tags: c#, wcf

I'm trying to write something to help me monitor my WCF services in a custom way. For that, my intention is to write a class implementing a service contract, lets call it IMonitorService, and whenever I want to host any of my normal services, lets say IBusinessService, I'd like to be able to create the normal endpoints for my business service and in addition an endpoint implementing IMonitorService. That way I can call all the monitor endpoints from all my services and read what I need. Is this even possible? 
I'm not saying it is possible to do this way but something like this would be great:

```
var serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(BusinessService), baseAddresses);
var monitorService = new MonitorService(servicehost.Description);
serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IMonitorService), whatever_binding, monitorService);
```

I know microsoft already does this for IMetadataExchange and discovery endpoints but I can't seem to understand  how to do it myself. How are those implemented?

Currently I'm resorting to open 2 service hosts and chaining their open/close events to that the main one closes the monitoring one and it is less than ideal. Even if it is not as simple as I hope it would be, I'm open to easier alternatives than what I'm doing now.

Comment: In short, no (at least as far as I know).  A service host can only host one service (which can have multiple endpoints).  The `IMetadataExchange` endpoint is a special case, I believe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to do what you want, but it is not easy to do. I did it once, but honestly and took quite a bit of work, but not sure how much any of that stuff has changed (in my case, I wanted a regular HTTP endpoint before WebHttpBinding came around, so it was actually a lot more complex).

It's possible this is a lot easier now, but in case it is useful, here's some articles I wrote about it back then:

- http://winterdom.com/2006/10/howimetadataexchangeishosted
- http://winterdom.com/2006/11/hackingmywayintoanarbitraryendpointinawcfservice

The resulting code from that investigation can be found here: http://quickcounters.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#QuickCounters_net2/WCFSupport/QuickCounters.Wcf/InstrumentedServiceAttribute.cs

In particular, look at the code for the AddHttpGetDispatcher() method.

Comment: Thanks @tomasr, its a lot of code but looks promising. I'm flagging your comment as the answer but, I apologize for stealing your glory, a comment in you blog post lead me to [this page](http://codestink.blogspot.com/2010/03/standard-endpoints-in-wcf-40.html) which talks about how to do it in v4 which, as your figured out, seems a bit easier.

Comment: No worries. As I said, I haven't looked at that code in years, and had not run into a case to do it anyway :) Happy that it is indeed easier now.